# Cognos force 0 on group by

Tags: group-by, aggregate, cognos

I've got a requirement to built a list report to show volume by 3 grouped by columns. The issue i'm having is if nothing happened on specific days for the specific grouped columns, i cant force it to show 0.

what i'm currently getting is something like:

ABC | AA | 01/11/2017 | 1

ABC | AA    | 03/11/2017 | 2

ABC |   AA  | 05/11/2017 |  1

what i need is:

ABC | AA |  01/11/2017 |    1

ABC | AA |  02/11/2017 |    0

ABC | AA |  03/11/2017 |    2

ABC | AA |  04/11/2107 |    0

ABC | AA |  05/11/2017 |    1

ive tried going down the route of unioning a "dummy" query with no query filters, however there are days where nothing has happened, at all, for those first 2 columns so it doesn't always populate.

Hope that makes sense, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

to anyone who wanted an answer i figured it out. Query 1 for just the dates, as there will always be some form of event happening daily so will always give a unique date range.

query 2 for the other 2 "grouped by" columns.

Create a data item in each with "1" as the result (but would work with anything as long as they are the same).

Query 1, left join to Query 2 on this new data item.

This then gives a full combination of all 3 columns needed. The resulting "Query 3" can then be left joined again to get the measures. Final query (depending on aggregation) may need to have the measure data item wrapped with a COALESCE/ISNULL to create a 0 on those days nothing happened.